# Stop Progressbar manual scrolling in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have already posted my query [here](http://www.anddev.org/prevent_manual_moving_of_seekbar_widget-t13048.html), but unfortunately, not getting the required support for this simple query.

I am using a progressbar widget in my application to show the download progress.

In the current state, I am able to manually move the slider back and forth while download is progressing. How can I prevent the manual moving of progressbar, instead it works only based on

`progressbar.setProgress(progressbar.getProgress() + 1024);` -- currently this works perfect, but I need to prevent the manual moving of progressbar during download.

Answer (score 2):

There is example code on the Android developers website:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Have you followed that? I doubt the progress bar is scrollable by default, it would be a seek bar then

Comment: +1 - he even states in his question on anddev that it's a seekbar! @Rony: You definitely want to use a progress bar not a seekbar. The link Donal gave will show you how to do that.

Comment: Oh my! I think you have taken my question in the wrong way. I admit that initially I used seekbar, but on advice from anddev, I used progressbar; both with progressbar and seekbar, I am able to manually move the slideer.

My only question is, how can I disable this feature of manually moving the progressbar. If no such facility is available, then it is altogether a bad impression for android progressbar.

Comment: There should not be an option to slide the indicator on a progressbar at all,it would make it a seekbar, are you sure you have removed all seekbar code?